# How to make an associative array with elements from an array as its key and use arrays for corresponding values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have arrays $devices,$port

```
print_r($devices);
Array(
[0] => cisco1
[1] => cisco2
 )

print_r($port);
Array
(
[0] => Port1/1/1
[1] => Port1/1/10
[2] => Port1/1/11
)
```

I want to create an array $devlist which would be something like this:

```
Array(

[cisco1] =>Port1/1/1
           Port1/1/10
           Port1/1/11

[cisco2] =>Port2/1/1
           Port2/1/10
           Port2/1/11

)
```

My point is there is an array of devices($devices) and arrays of ports that are there in each of the device. 
The **$port** array gets created newly for each device in the $device array.

What i have tried so far:

```
foreach ($devices as $value)
{
$port=();
//iam polling the respective device and getting a list of ports available for that device in array **$port**

array_push($devices[$value], $port);
}
```

This method generates an error  "array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given"

Kindly excuse me if this seems an easy question becoz iam new to php and scripting as well:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $devlist = array();
    foreach ($devices as $value)
    {
            $port=();
            //iam polling the respective device and getting a list of ports available for that device in array **$port**

            $devlist[$value] = $port;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this? If so, i don't understand why, when you could just use the values from $ports for each $device?

```
$devices = array
(
    'cisco1', 'cisco2'
);

$ports = array 
(
    'Port1/1/1',
    'Port1/1/10',
    'Port1/1/11'
);

$dev_list = array();

foreach ($devices as $device) 
{
    $dev_list[$device] = array();

    foreach ($ports as $port) 
    {
        array_push($dev_list[$device], $port);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($dev_list);
echo '</pre>';

Array
(
    [cisco1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Port1/1/1
            [1] => Port1/1/10
            [2] => Port1/1/11
        )

    [cisco2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Port1/1/1
            [1] => Port1/1/10
            [2] => Port1/1/11
        )

)
```

Comment: yup i should have done like this: $dev_list[$device] = $port;  ur detailed post made it a lot clearer :) as i said iam a bit of a noob still.....thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, but why do you want that? You're gonne dublicate all the values in the new array, instead of just using the $ports-array?

Comment: $ports will not be same for each device in $devices....the above one that i had given was just for an example.....so $ports will be different for each $device in $devices...so no duplication right?

Comment: Right, but then you could just setup your $devices-array with cisco1, cisco2 etc.. as keys with empty arrays as values from start, and then add the ports as values, instead of putting them to $ports-array first? :)

Comment: i would first have to do some manupulation on the ports array like array_unique....so i would hav to get the list of ports in an array first manipulate them and assign them on the fly:)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `foreach` or a `for` loop but the main thing is that you have to use [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

**Solution One:**

```
$devlist = array();
foreach($devices as $key => $device){
$devlist[$device] = ${"port".($key+1)};
}
```

**Solution Two:**

```
$devlist = array();
$size = sizeof($devices);
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
$devlist[$devices[$i]] = ${"port".($i+1)};
}
```

Comment: $devlist[$devices[$i]] = ${"port".($i+1)}; This line would assign $port1,$port2......to $devlist[$devices] right?? i had edited my question and removed $port1,$port2 etc.......there is jus 1 array $port which gets overwritten foreach ($devices as $value)...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want something like this:

```
$arr = array
(
    'cisco1' => array 
    (
        'Port1/1/1', 
        'Port1/1/10',
        'Port1/1/11'
    ),
    'cisco2' => array
    (
        'Port1/1/1', 
        'Port1/1/10',
        'Port1/1/11'
    )
);

foreach($arr as $key => $value) // use the foreach-loop like this to get both keys and values
{
    echo "$key: <br />-" . implode('<br />-', $value) . '<br /><br />';
}
```

prints:

```
cisco1: 
-Port1/1/1
-Port1/1/10
-Port1/1/11

cisco2: 
-Port1/1/1
-Port1/1/10
-Port1/1/11
```

Comment: No,iam afraid u misunderstood ,my question was how do i form that $arr in the first place? i have $cisco1 and $cisco2 ...how do i make an array that has cisco1,cisco2 etc as its key and $port array as its value?

Comment: Added a new answer, hope it helps. :) But if that's what you're looking for, i don't understand?